In node js - required body params matching with db value in mysql
In Node.js, I created an API to check if a customer exists based on their mobile number or email. However, when I pass values that aren’t present in the database, it still shows a "success" response. How can I write the logic to return an appropriate message if the customer is not found?
Node js - model file code --
export async function existing_customer_check(data){
    const email = data.email;
    const mobile = data.mobile;

    const register_customer_check_query = `SELECT email , mobile FROM users WHERE email = ? || mobile = ? `;
    
    try{
  const result = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    pool.query(register_customer_check_query,[email,mobile],(error,result,fields)=>{
        if(error){
                reject(error);
        }
        else{
            resolve(result);
        }
    })
  })
  return result;
    }catch(error){
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
}

controller file
export async function existing_customer_check(data){
    const email = data.email;
    const mobile = data.mobile;

    const register_customer_check_query = `SELECT email , mobile FROM users WHERE email = ? || mobile = ? `;
    
    try{
  const result = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    pool.query(register_customer_check_query,[email,mobile],(error,result,fields)=>{
        if(error){
                reject(error);
        }
        else{
            resolve(result);
        }
    })
  })
  return result;
    }catch(error){
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
}


Both the files are having the same content. Probably a mistake?

Of note, it is highly suggested that you convert that statement into a stored procedure and instead call it and provide the parameters for it, that way they are at least validated on the database end , and idealistically you would validate them on the front end with angular as well .  TLDR version - do it so you don't give a freebie hackable database to the internet.

If the conditions you are looking for are not in the database, it will not return an error. Instead, it will return an empty value. For example, it will return an empty array. You need to check its occupancy and create an error such as no record found and pass it on. If an empty array is returned, you can check as follows:
if (result.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('No customer found!);
  }


I tried this logic in the controller not worked as well

@MAVEN Can you share the code you tried?
